# delete & back space not working in radeditor

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, radeditor

I am using radeditor in my project.
I have created some custom tags which I insert in text area
Bellow is demo html code of this tags with text

```
this is demo<var is-end="false" conditionid="439726" conditionfield="FELT001" conditionlabel="new co" title="Start of condition: new co" style="display: inline-block; width: 16px; height: 16px; margin-right: 3px; background-image: url('http://localhost/dialogportal.com/images/icons/condition-begin.gif'); background-repeat: no-repeat;" contenteditable="false"></var> text <var is-end="false" conditionid="439726" conditionfield="FELT001" conditionlabel="new co" title="Start of condition: new co" style="display: inline-block; width: 16px; height: 16px; margin-right: 3px; background-image: url('http://localhost/dialogportal.com/images/icons/condition-begin.gif'); background-repeat: no-repeat;" contenteditable="false"></var>again this will have conditions<var is-end="true" conditionid="439726" title="End of condition: new co" style="display: inline-block; width: 16px; height: 16px; margin-left: 3px; background-image: url('http://localhost/dialogportal.com/images/icons/condition-end.gif'); background-repeat: no-repeat;" contenteditable="false"></var><var is-end="true" conditionid="439726" title="End of condition: new co" style="display: inline-block; width: 16px; height: 16px; margin-left: 3px; background-image: url('http://localhost/dialogportal.com/images/icons/condition-end.gif'); background-repeat: no-repeat;" contenteditable="false"></var>&nbsp;which we have to test
```

It looks like something like this 
[image]

Here we can see two VAR tags together. Problem occurs with them in chrome & safari.
nor using right & left arrows I can not go through this var tags neither using back space & delete works with this.

This problem occurs only in chrome & safari & not in firefox & IE.

Answer (score 3):

The editor attaches to a number of events in its content area - and one of those is, of course, onkeydown.
Because of certain browser quirks, the editor needs to execute some code when BACK or DELETE is pressed.

When you register your own handler in OnClientLoad, your code executes after the editor's own event handler.

Unfortunately there is no "standard" way to override this behavior. Yet - the following code is a fairly simple approach that should do the trick - all you need to do is add this script after your editor declaration.
Essentially, as you can see, the code overrides the editor's private _onKeyDown method and lets you execute your own code there.

```
<script>            
           Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor.prototype.old_onKeyDown = Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor.prototype._onKeyDown; 
           Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor.prototype._onKeyDown = function (e) 
           { 
             //Write your own here 
             if (e.keyCode == 8) //BACK was pressed 
             {            
                //if you do not want the editor to execute its own code cancel event 
                return $telerik.cancelRawEvent(e);               
             }            
             //Call original code 
             this.old_onKeyDown(e); 
           } 
           </script>
```

Please note that this is a bit of a hack. While we do not expect to change this method's name in the foreseeable future, it is still not a public method, so there are no guarantees.

Comment: this will just cancel the Back event. Then how do I delete the tags with back space or delete ?